# Get user profiles in SharePoint 2010 using server object model

Tags: 2010, user-profile

I am writing a console application. And, want to get all the user profiles who are under the given specific user and down the user profiles hierarchy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods that should help you here:

[GetPeers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.getpeers.aspx)

[GetManagers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.getmanagers.aspx)

[GetDirectReports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.getdirectreports.aspx)

There is no "easy way" that I've found but you can write your own helper classes that use these methods.